# Sending data to file_get_contents

Tags: php

According to other posts about this, my code seems fine, however it doesn't work.

```
$postdata = http_build_query($_SESSION);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$mailBody = file_get_contents('customorderemailtemplate.html', false, $context);
```

In `customorderemailtemplate.html`, I use `$_POST` but it's not working -- and I am sure that `$_SESSION` is not empty when passing it to `$postdata`.

Comment: `customorderemailtemplate.html` is a file on your local disk? You're not going out to make an HTTP request on another server for it?! Then a) the whole HTTP context doesn't apply at all and b) an .html file will probably never be actively interpreted by anything. – Sure you're not just looking for `require 'customorderemailtemplate.html'`?

Comment: In `.html` files you cannot use `$_POST`.

Comment: I can use PHP within .html files.

Comment: perhaps a better option is `curl()`

Comment: Still, using the "URL" `'customorderemailtemplate.html'`, **you're not make an HTTP request anywhere.** You're just reading the file from disk, so there's no web server involved which would run PHP over it.

Comment: I see - so I could add the `http://` part to fix my issue. However I'll go with deceze's, answer which seems to be good practice. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that your code will create an HTTP request to a web server, which would process the POST data, invoke PHP and interpolate the values into the HTML. This won't happen, since your "URL" points to a local file; it doesn't start with `http://`. So the file contents will be read from disk, and that's it.

It's also a rather insane way to "render" a template this way, if it would work at all. You're probably just looking for this:

```
ob_start();
require 'customorderemailtemplate.html';
$mailBody = ob_get_clean();
```

Inside `customorderemailtemplate.html` you can use `<?php echo $_SESSION['blah']; ?>` to output values.

Comment: Thanks - will go with this, seems better practice than actually adding the `http://` part to make it work.